# HTTP 403 Forbidden in IE when javascript location.href="home.aspx"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a weird thing.
There is a cancel button in my app, that has onclick javascript event that does 1 thing only: location.href = "home.aspx".

**Works fine in Firefox.**

**Doesnt work in IE.**

IE navigates to the root and displays "HTTP 403 Forbidden"

[image]

Any idea what is going on ??

Answer (score 0):

Change `location.href = "home.aspx"` to `window.location.href = "/home.aspx"` to make sure it redirects to the root of your webserver.

If that fails, then try:

`window.location = "http://www.yourdomainhere.com/home.aspx"`

If absolute links are ok.

Comment: True.
Perfectly works in Firefox.
Not working in IE !! :( So weird.